# Como puedo filtrar el valor de un HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un tipo de carrito de compras, creando una lista de productos , a través de javascript, hasta ahí todo bien, ahora cuando le doy click a algun producto logre que me retornara un HTMLCollection en forma de array, ya que hay 9 productos tengo HTMLCollection(9)

```js
let prod = document.getElementsByClassName('product')

for(let i = 0;i < prod.length;i++){
  prod[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(prod[i])
  })
}
```

en el prod[i] me devuelve un producto con esta estructura

```html
<div class="product">
      <p class="title">Producto 1</p>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <p class="price">$ 100</p>
    </div>
```

Ahora lo que no logro hacer es obtener solo el nombre que seria 'Producto 1'
y el precio que seria '100'

para posteriormente colocarlo en una tabla.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar o decirme alguna otra forma de conseguir lo que quiero . muchas gracias de antemano :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con jQuery seria mas facil. pero con vanilla javascript seria asi:

```js
let prod = document.getElementsByClassName('product')

for(let i = 0;i < prod.length;i++){
  prod[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    let pro = prod[i].firstChild.nextElementSibling;
    let price = pro.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    
    console.log("Producto: " + pro.innerHTML + "  Precio: " + price.innerHTML);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
      <p class="title">Producto 1</p>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <p class="price">$ 100</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <p class="title">Producto 2</p>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <p class="price">$ 1002</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <p class="title">Producto 3</p>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <p class="price">$ 500</p>
    </div>
```